# Cordova error while adding android in mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova, sdk

I'm working on a macbook and developing with cordova. Now, I want to create an Android apk, but, when I type `cordova platform add android` I get this:

```
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
```

Ok, this message should be very clear about what to do next, but don't know what to do. When I search I keep getting how to solve this in Windows and can't follow steps.

What (and how) should I do?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I've already installed Android SDK when trying to compile apk.

**More info:**

As I couldn't install ANT, I uninstalled it: `brew uninstall ant`. But when `brew install ant`again I got:

```
$ brew install ant
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.tar.gz
==> Best Mirror http://apache.rediris.es/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "ant"
Download failed: http://apache.rediris.es/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.tar.gz
```

Comment: If you can, please add some more information to your question. It would be helpful to know these things: Have you installed the Android SDK? Have you added the `tools` and `platform-tools` paths to the `PATH` variable? Are you sure `ANT` is installed? Which version of everything are you using? Thanks.

Comment: how do I add tools to platform-tools? I think ANT is installed, I'll check

Comment: No, I don't have ANT installed, I'm trying to install it, but when I type ant --version I get: ant command not found

Answer (score 1):

Some things to make sure you have completed before starting w/ Android:

Make sure ANT is installed:

Try `ant --version`, if `command not found` you need to install ANT.

The easiest way I have found is to use `Homebrew`. If you do not have homebrew installed, [get it here](http://brew.sh/)

Once installed run

```
homebrew update
homebrew install ant
```

Unpack Android SDK:

Download and unpack the SDK package, place it in an easy to find location.

Then add the `tools` and `platform-tools` paths to your global `PATH`, like this:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

add this line:

```
export PATH=/path/to/android/sdk/tools:/path/to/adnroid/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Exit the terminal and re open the terminal.

Now you should be able to run `cordova platform add android` in your project folder.

Comment: Something really strange is happening: When I do `brew install ant`I get this: `Warning: ant-1.9.3 already installed`. But when I do `ant --version`I get this: `-bash: ant: command not found`

Comment: Have you added the paths yet? You might not need to update or install ANT, it may just be an issue with the paths

Comment: Well, I unistalled ant and, when doing `brew install ant` I get this:   `==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.tar.gz
==> Best Mirror http://apache.rediris.es/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "ant"
Download failed: http://apache.rediris.es/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.tar.gz`

Comment: I'll text it again in a edit so you can see better the message